# How the mergeMap operator works?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I tried to understand, how mergeMap worked in this example and still don't understand. Can you help me?

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';


// emit value every 1s
const source$ = interval(1000);

source$
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(
      // project
      val => interval(5000).pipe(take(2)),
      // resultSelector
      (oVal, iVal, oIndex, iIndex) => [oIndex, oVal, iIndex, iVal],
      // concurrent
      2
    )
  )
  /*
        Output:
        [0, 0, 0, 0] <--1st inner observable
        [1, 1, 0, 0] <--2nd inner observable
        [0, 0, 1, 1] <--1st inner observable
        [1, 1, 1, 1] <--2nd inner observable
        [2, 2, 0, 0] <--3rd inner observable
        [3, 3, 0, 0] <--4th inner observable
*/
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-r3gcr4?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

I don't understand the values displayed in the console

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's decompose logic to simple threads:

Your `source$` timer emits values 0, 1, 2, 3... every second. And this thread goes through your pipe, where `mergeMap` is used to modify your thread.

Concurrent value `2` means every two input values will be passed and wait the execution for finish, then next 2 values will be passed and execute, etc.

You have selector: [old Index, old Value, current Index, current Value], so let's see:

- first value is `0`, goes from `source$`, will be generate `[0, 0, 0 ,0]`, because incoming value is `0`, and current value in `mergeMap` from `interval(5000)` is `0` either,
- second value `1` goes after 1000 ms from `source$`, and will be passed to mergeMap, then mutate to value `[1, 1, 0, 0]`, where `0, 0` - as first value and index from `interval(5000)`. For each pipe value, new `interval(5000)` will be generated.
- after 5000 ms, it generates second value and index from `mergeMap` `1, 1`, so in first pipe thread with value `0, 0` it generates output: `[0, 0, 1, 1]`. In second pipe with value `1, 1`, it generates output `[1, 1, 1, 1]`.
- and now next two values goes to `mergeMap` from the `source$`: `2, 2` and `3, 3`. So again we repeat the steps with new `interval(5000)` values `0, 0` and `1, 1` after 5000ms. So it generates `[2, 2, 0, 0]` and `[3, 3, 0, 0]`, and after 5000ms `[2, 2, 1, 1]` and `[3, 3, 1, 1]`.

And so go on.

Comment: Thank you very much Tony Marko for your help. I now understand how mergeMap works. However,  you forgot to mention take(2). It is take(2) that explains why the numbers emitted by inner observable never exceed 1.

Comment: I though it's obvious :)